# including foundation with sass in a django project

Tags: django, sass, zurb-foundation

I have a django project under a virtualenv.
I included the django-zurb-foundation 5.3.0 package to use foundation but this version only include static css files.

It's my first time using django and normally i use foundation with sass using bower and grunt.

How can i do to use the sass version of foundation?
What should be the files tree?

UPDATE

i installed django compressor and i got it work on local, it works perfectly, but i cannot get it to work on my production server:
on local env i have a CACHE folder with  the css static files in it and the html page call correctly the file from there.

On the prod site instead, it doesnt create the CACHE folder and it doesnt render the path to it and it keeps the path to the scss file.

What am i doing wrong?

It seems like compressor isnt working on the prod server, i'm afraid i'm doing something wrong with django settings.py since i'm new to it.
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard of a few people using [django-bower](https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower) with foundation, personally I have not played with it but its worth looking into if you have not already.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't find a reason to use a third party Django application to do that, using front-end frameworks like foundation or Bootstrap is as simple as compiling the less or sass source files to a css file and include it in your html (`<link rel="stylesheet"...`).

With Django you can use Bower and Grunt without any problem because they're independent and totally configurable to fill your needs. What I do with bower is to create a `.bowerrc` file at the same level of the `bower.json` file with the `directory` setting pointing to the main static folder, something like:

```
{
    "directory": "my_django_app/static/bower_components"
}
```

Talking about the django-compressor app all that I can say is I don't recommend to use it in a production environment, it has some performance problems and personally I prefer the static files to be responsibility of the front-end dev instead of the back-end dev. For example you will need to have source maps for your javascript for debugging purposes and I don't remember if it's possible with this plugin.

Instead of using the django-compressor you can use a grunt plugin to to it, I've done one that may help you to do so: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-django-compressor